# update statusbar's text property in the form by another form's button's click event

Tags: c++builder

Hi I am unable to update the status bar's text property in the form by another form's button click. It is successfully compiled and able to run until I clicked  The error I got is "Access violation at address: XXXXXXXX....."

C++ Builder XE7 in Win 7 is used.

Form1:

```
#include "Main.h"
#include "minor.h"
....
TForm1 *Form1;
TForm2 *Form2;
....
```

Form2:

```
#include "minor.h"
#include "Main.h"
....
TForm2 *Form2;
TForm1 *Form1;
....
__fastcall TForm2::TForm2(TComponent* Owner)
: TForm(Owner)
{
TButton* btnTest2 = new TButton(this);
btnTest2->Height = 50;
btnTest2->Width = 200;
btnTest2->Left = 220;
btnTest2->Top = 50;
btnTest2->Caption = "Updated Statusbar Button";
btnTest2->Visible = true;
btnTest2->Enabled = true;
btnTest2->Parent = this;
btnTest2->OnClick = &ButtonClicked2; // Create your own event here manually!
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm2::ButtonClicked2(TObject *Sender)
{
Form1->statusbarMain->Panels->Items[0]->Text = "Hello2";   // PROBLEM!!!
}
```

Any idea why it got problems?
Please advise.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Form2 unit is declaring its own `Form1` variable that is separate from the `Form1` variable in the Form1 unit, and that second variable is not being initialized to anything meaningful.  That is why your code is crashing - you are accessing the wrong `Form1` variable.

You need to get rid of the `Form1` variable in the Form2 unit and `#include` Form1's header file instead (it should already have an `extern` declaration for Form1's `Form1` variable).  This is also necessary because Form2 needs the full declaration of the `TForm1` class in order to access its members, such as `statusbarMain`.

Same thing with the `Form2` variable that you are declaring in the Form1 unit.  You need to remove it and use `#include "Form2.hpp"` instead (which should have a suitable `extern` declaration).

Form1.h:

```
...
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
__published:
    TStatusBar *statusbarMain;
    ...
};
extern TForm1 *Form1;
...
```

Form1.cpp:

```
#include "Main.h"
#include "minor.h"
#include "Form2.hpp" // <-- add this
....
TForm1 *Form1;
//TForm2 *Form2; // <-- get rid of this
....
```

Form2.h:

```
...
class TForm2 : public TForm
{
    ...
};
extern TForm2 *Form2;
...
```

Form2.cpp:

```
#include "minor.h"
#include "Main.h"
#include "Form1.hpp" // <-- add this
....
TForm2 *Form2;
//TForm1 *Form1; // <-- get rid of this
...
void __fastcall TForm2::ButtonClicked2(TObject *Sender)
{
    Form1->statusbarMain->Panels->Items[0]->Text = "Hello2";
}
```

Comment: Thanks It works!  Actually main.h actually corresponds to Form1.hpp  and minor.h to  Form2.hpp. Glad that it works. Thanks, Would it be better if the hpp and cpp share the same names, lessening the confusions. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, a .cpp and its corresponding .h/.hpp file should match names.  The compiler doesn't care, but doing so helps the IDE group related files together in the Project Manager and Code Editor, and it helps you keep the files organized.